# Filling the entire screen in multiple screen resolutions, densities

Tags: android, drawrect, pixel, screens

I want to draw a rectangle that fills the entire screen on all Android phones, all resolution, all screen densities.Everything... :)
First from what I understand Canvas.drawRect use as dimensions values in pixel. Hope this is correct.
Being new to Android I thought that if I simply write like this it will be sufficient, since at this moment there is no Android device with a resolution higher than 1024x1024 pixels:

```
ScreenWidth = 1024;
ScreenHeight = 1024;
canvas.drawRect(0,0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, mLoadPaint);
```

But it seems that on some devices this Rectangle doesn't fill the entire screen. What is strange and I can't explain myself is that this doesn't happens always but at a point in time...
Anyway it seems that there is a problem with the code so I would like to change it to look something like this, but now sure it metrics.widthPixels and metrics.heightPixels will solve my problem:

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
canvas.drawRect(0,0, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, mLoadPaint);
```

I want to know if this is correct, and if this piece of code will cover all screens, and the rectangle will fill the entire screen.
Of course with this approach I will have to take care also of the screen orientation, as it seems that the values are swapped between them when the screen is in Landscape.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is going *into* the rectangle? I'm fairly certain your second option (using metrics) should work, and you shouldn't have to worry about values being swapped, as long as your drawRect method is somewhere that will be called when the orientation changes (e.g. onCreate()).

Comment: It's a filter, a brightness filter, so it's going...the user activity... :) I need to worry about because the rectangle is draw onCreate's service (it's a service) but the orientation can change anytime during service lifetime. I already implemented this and works on emulator and my phone, but hey, 1024x1024 worked also on emulator and my phone... :)

Comment: If it's got a UI, it has to be in an activity. The activity is destroyed and rebuilt (e.g. onCreate() is called again) when the orientation changes, unless you specifically override it not to do so.

Comment: Trust me the drawing is made from the service, without any activity. I'm painting all over the screen, it's quite cool actually :)

Comment: Interesting. It's probably outside of something I can help with then. I was under the impression you couldn't do anything like that without having root privileges.

Comment: Ok, just stick with my method but increase the size, to make sure that it covers all resolution,densities :) ?             ScreenWidth = 2048;
ScreenHeight = 2048;
canvas.drawRect(0,0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, mLoadPaint);

Comment: I thought you said it was working with the metrics values? Why not stick with that? You could always add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your manifest and override onConfigurationChanged() to handle the portrait vs. landscape values. Alternatively, rather than make it insanely larger than necessary, I suppose you could avoid this by just passing `Math.max(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)` as both parameters. This way it would be a square with the widest side the exact width of the widest side of the screen.

Comment: It's working, but I have to deal with screen reorientation, redraw the rectangle, invalidate etc... And don't know if it's worth or just increase the rectangle area cause this was the problem...

Comment: Yeah, if orientation of the rectangle's not important, I'd just pass the widest value for width and height, making a square. Shouldn't have to redraw/invalidate anything, as long as it's centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try canvas.drawColor(int color)